# Redirect urls by pattern to another urls in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I want redirect all post like this in htaccess:

```
https://www.example.com/{year}/{month}/{day}/mainurl/addess/
```

to:

```
https://www.example.com/mainurl/addess/
```

That `{year}/{month}/{day}/` is variable.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using a CMS of any kind? Only "{year}/{month}/{day}/ is variable"? So, `mainurl/addess/` is a fixed string?

Comment: Tanks your answer. yes. I use wordpress. and {year}/{month}/{day} is Permalink in general menu of wp-admin.

Comment: a real samle: 
https://www.example.com/2013/12/14/url55/amp/
redirected to 
https://www.example.com/url55/amp/

Answer (score 0):

> I use wordpress. and {year}/{month}/{day} is Permalink in general menu of wp-admin.

To clarify, you will need to have already changed your permalink structure inside WordPress for the following redirect to work.

In order to redirect `https://www.example.com/2013/12/14/url55/amp/` to `https://www.example.com/url55/amp/`, where the `2013/12/14/` (year/month/day) part is variable then try the following *before* your existing WordPress directives:

```
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d/(url55/amp/) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Note that this is a temporary (302) redirect. Change it to `301` if this is intended to be permanent, but only after you have confirmed that it is working OK. (301 redirects are cached hard by the browser by default, so can make testing problematic.)

To make the above redirect more generic, ie. to redirect `/<year>/<month>/<day>/<something1>/<something2>/` to `/<something1>/<something2>/` then make the above regex more generic. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d/([^/]+/[^/]+/) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Tanks my dear! Its WORKED!

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (click the greyed out check mark on the left below the arrows), much appreciated, thanks. :) Once you have 15+ rep you can also upvote answers you find useful.